# How can we find a Carmichael number near a huge given number?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, recreational-mathematics, carmichael-numbers

> How can I find a Carmichael number near a huge given number , say $10^{100}$ ?

My best trial was to find suitable $k$ such that $6k+1$ , $12k+1$ , $18k+1$ are prime and the product as near as possible at $10^{100}$. But the results are still very unsatisfying :

$$9999999999999999999999999995194780645298842465772438047052058885837645928421429394846343577780058169$$
and $$10000000000000000000000000000405929367865700162694655745350302085810080768959837103297359653235421369$$

What can I do for significant better results ?

Comment: These are not significantly better, but, using Greg Martin's answer from [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4736585/ratio-between-largest-and-smallest-prime-factor) I found $$9999999999999999999999999999796847326318726073975133650980786082646990292703172311852106037044385201$$ with $a=1$, $b=2$, and $c=15$ and $$10000000000000000000000000000090165987523064535571479173405047627125202459134286779355757424137024721$$ with $a=3$, $b=29$, and $c=194$. These were the best results I could find for $a < b < c < 200$ and for $a\leq 12$ together with $a < b < c < 1000$.

Comment: @jorisperrenet  Again great work ! You answered many questions I had about Carmichael-numbers.  Do you happen to have a challenge concerning Carmichael-numbers for other users ? The only one I am aware of is Martin Hopf's challenge to find a Carmichael-number with more than $100\ 000$ digits and less than $100$ factors. Maybe, you can answer one more question : Is there a third Carmichael-number with only odd digits in the decimal expansion upto 2^64 ( I found two) ?