# Ratio between largest and smallest prime factor

Tags: elementary-number-theory, recreational-mathematics, prime-factorization, carmichael-numbers

For a Carmichael-number $N$ let $p$ be the smallest and $q$ the largest prime factor. Consider $r:=\frac{q}{p}$. We could call a Carmichael "balanced" , if $r\approx 1$ , say $r<1.1$.

> Can $r$ be arbitary close to $1$ ?

In the Carmichael numbers upto $10^{16}$ , the number with the smallest ratio is $$33432760972801= 30241\cdot 32257\cdot 34273$$ $r\approx 1.13$

Comment: Searching the database up to $2^{64}$ I found $$156922160709748897=521137\cdot 530443\cdot 567667$$ with $r \approx 1.09$ and the even better $$8005519274743488961 = 1942183\cdot  2001037\cdot 2059891$$ with $r \approx 1.06$.

Comment: An interesting side note to Greg Martin's answer is that we can generate $8005519274743488961$ using $a=33$, $b=34$, $c=35$ and $n=m+abc=58854$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Conjecturally (on the Hardy–Littlewood prime 3-tuples conjecture) the answer is yes.

The following is shown in Chapter 14 of O. Ore's *Number Theory and Its History* and is not too hard to verify by hand: Given any three positive, pairwise relatively prime integers $a<b<c$, let $m$ be the solution to the congruence $m(ab+bc+ca)+a+b+c\equiv0\pmod{abc}$. Then for any integer $n \equiv m\pmod{abc}$, if each of $an+1$, $bn+1$, and $cn+1$ is prime, then $(an+1)(bn+1)(cn+1)$ is a Carmichael number.

Conjecturally that simultaneous primality should happen infinitely often; and in this family the ratio of the largest to smallest prime factor approaches $c/a$ as $n\to\infty$, which can be chosen arbitrarily close to $1$ (by choosing $(a,b,c)=(2d-1,2d,2d+1)$ for example).

Comment: Using this answer I've constructed an 881-digit Carmichael number $(an+1)(bn+1)(cn+1)$ with $a=2d-1$, $b=2d$ and $c=2d+1$ where $d=10^{73}+344393$ and $n=m+abc$, calculating $m$ as specified above. This results in $r\approx 1 + 10^{-73}$.

Comment: What is $m$ here ?

Comment: @Peter, see the answer: "let $m$ be the solution to the congruence ...".

Comment: @jorisperrenet  This solution is only unique upto abc. If I choose the one between 0 and abc , I do not get prime factors.

Comment: But I managed to finally find a Carmichael-number with three $300$digit prime factors shown [here](http://factordb.com/index.php?id=1100000004674237236)

Comment: @Peter, after double-checking my comment here I realised I indeed made a mistake. It should be $d=10^{73}+344939$. And yes, I meant the $m$ between $0$ and $abc$. Sorry for all the confusion. The value of the Carmichael number becomes $$138240000000000...5718940548463118849\,.$$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147248/discussion-between-peter-and-jorisperrenet).